# Phoenix-5.0.0-HBase-2.0 installation problem

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

As descibed in installation [guid](http://phoenix.apache.org/installation.html) I copied file **phoenix-5.0.0-HBase-2.0-server.jar** into hbase library path **/opt/hbase/lib/**. The **Hbase** crashes at startup. If I remove it, **hbase** starting and running well again. What is the problem?

I use **hadoop**  version:

```
$ hadoop version
Hadoop 3.1.3
Source code repository https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r ba631c436b806728f8ec2f54ab1e289526c90579
Compiled by ztang on 2019-09-12T02:47Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum ec785077c385118ac91aadde5ec9799
This command was run using /opt/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-3.1.3.jar
```

**Hbase** version:

```
hbase(main):001:0> version
2.0.6, rd65cccb5fda039217954a558c65bda423e0d6df3, Wed Aug 14 15:44:48 UTC 2019
Took 0.0003 seconds
```

Error details in log file **/opt/hbase/logs/hbase-master.log**:

```
2020-06-06 14:54:48,454 ERROR [main] regionserver.HRegionServer: Failed construction RegionServer
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.phoenix.trace.PhoenixMetricsSink.init(Lorg/apache/commons/configuration/SubsetConfiguration;)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig.getPlugin(MetricsConfig.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.newSink(MetricsSystemImpl.java:529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.configureSinks(MetricsSystemImpl.java:501)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.configure(MetricsSystemImpl.java:480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.start(MetricsSystemImpl.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.init(MetricsSystemImpl.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.init(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.initialize(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics.BaseSourceImpl$DefaultMetricsSystemInitializer.init(BaseSourceImpl.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics.BaseSourceImpl.<init>(BaseSourceImpl.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.MetricsIOSourceImpl.<init>(MetricsIOSourceImpl.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.MetricsIOSourceImpl.<init>(MetricsIOSourceImpl.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.MetricsRegionServerSourceFactoryImpl.createIO(MetricsRegionServerSourceFactoryImpl.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.MetricsIO.<init>(MetricsIO.java:35)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile.<clinit>(HFile.java:195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.<init>(HRegionServer.java:536)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.<init>(HMaster.java:477)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:3050)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:3068)
2020-06-06 14:54:48,456 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Master: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster. 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:3057)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:3068)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.phoenix.trace.PhoenixMetricsSink.init(Lorg/apache/commons/configuration/SubsetConfiguration;)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig.getPlugin(MetricsConfig.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.newSink(MetricsSystemImpl.java:529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.configureSinks(MetricsSystemImpl.java:501)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.configure(MetricsSystemImpl.java:480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.start(MetricsSystemImpl.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl.init(MetricsSystemImpl.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.init(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.initialize(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics.BaseSourceImpl$DefaultMetricsSystemInitializer.init(BaseSourceImpl.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics.BaseSourceImpl.<init>(BaseSourceImpl.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.MetricsIOSourceImpl.<init>(MetricsIOSourceImpl.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.MetricsIOSourceImpl.<init>(MetricsIOSourceImpl.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.MetricsRegionServerSourceFactoryImpl.createIO(MetricsRegionServerSourceFactoryImpl.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.MetricsIO.<init>(MetricsIO.java:35)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFile.<clinit>(HFile.java:195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.<init>(HRegionServer.java:536)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.<init>(HMaster.java:477)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:3050)
    ... 5 more
```